# CSS Menu float half left and half right

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im wanting a way to float my menu half left and half right. So that the logo in the middle of the nav bar is floated center like it is and then half the menu items are on the left of the menu and the other half are on the right side.

This is my working directory for the code at the moment: http://theaamgroup.com/david-programs/brandit/

Basicly if thats not clear im wanting to make this nav bar here:
[image]

Look like this:

[image]

HTML

```
    <!-- Carousel
    ================================================== -->
    <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="lib/img/carousel/slide-01.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="lib/img/carousel/slide-02.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="lib/img/carousel/slide-03.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->    
    <!-- NAVBAR
    ================================================== -->
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
    <img src="lib/img/logos/Brandit_Logo.png" width="303" height="228" alt="Logos" class="MainLogo"/>
      <!-- Wrap the .navbar in .container to center it within the absolutely positioned parent. -->
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <!-- Responsive Navbar Part 1: Button for triggering responsive navbar (not covered in tutorial). Include responsive CSS to utilize. -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="brand" href="#"></a>
            <!-- Responsive Navbar Part 2: Place all navbar contents you want collapsed withing .navbar-collapse.collapse. -->
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
        </div><!-- /.navbar -->

      </div> <!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar-wrapper -->
```

CSS

```
/* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
body { padding-bottom: 40px; -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; -webkit-appearance: none; font-family: sans-serif; min-height: 416px; background-image: url('../img/bkg.png'); background-repeat: repeat; }

/* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */
.navbar-wrapper { position: absolute; z-index: 5; margin-top: -85px; width: 100% }
.navbar-wrapper .navbar { }
/* Remove border and change up box shadow for more contrast */
.navbar .navbar-inner { border: 0; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25); -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25); box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25); }
/* Downsize the brand/project name a bit */
.navbar .brand { padding: 14px 20px 16px; /* Increase vertical padding to match navbar links */ font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5); }
.navbar .nav > li > a { padding: 15px 20px }
/* Offset the responsive button for proper vertical alignment */
.MainLogo { position: absolute; left: 50%; right: 0; margin-top: -90px; margin-left: -152px; }

/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Carousel base class */
.carousel { margin-bottom: 60px }
.carousel .container { position: relative; z-index: 10; }
.carousel-control { height: 80px; margin-top: 0; font-size: 120px; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4); background-color: transparent; border: 0; z-index: 10; }
.carousel .item { height: 500px }
.carousel img { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; min-width: 100%; height: 500px; }
.carousel-caption { background-color: transparent; position: static; max-width: 550px; padding: 0 20px; margin-top: 200px; }
.carousel-caption h1,
.carousel-caption .lead { margin: 0; line-height: 1.25; color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4); }
.carousel-caption .btn { margin-top: 10px }


/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
@media (max-width: 979px) { 
    .container.navbar-wrapper { margin-bottom: 0; width: auto; }
    .navbar-wrapper { height: 50px; margin-top: -60px; }
    .navbar-inner { margin: -20px 0; }
    .navbar .nav > li { z-index: 0; }
    .MainLogo { margin-top: -115px; }
    .carousel .item { height: 500px }
    .carousel img { width: auto; height: 500px; }
    .marketing { margin-top: 30px; }
    .featurette { height: auto; padding: 0; }
    .featurette-image.pull-left,
    .featurette-image.pull-right { display: block; float: none; max-width: 40%; margin: 0 auto 20px; }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) { 
    .navbar-inner { border-radius: 0; }
    .btn-navbar { position: absolute; left: 85%; z-index: 5; }
    .MainLogo { margin-top: -185px; }
    .carousel .container { }
    .carousel .item { height: 300px }
    .carousel img { height: 300px }
    .carousel-caption { width: 65%; padding: 0 70px; margin-top: 100px; }
    .carousel-caption h1 { font-size: 30px }
    .carousel-caption .lead,
    .carousel-caption .btn { font-size: 18px }
    .marketing .span4 + .span4 { margin-top: 40px }
    .featurette-heading { font-size: 30px }
    .featurette .lead { font-size: 18px; line-height: 1.5; }
}
```

A little help to point me in the right direction would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post yor code here please. a link to a site helps no one ion the future when you site changes.

Comment: I suggest you create 2 top menu, 1 for left another for right.

Comment: Add your logo to the menu, then relatively position it at `top: -30px` or something.

Comment: ... Thank you for the code... can you add the pertinent info only and remove all the erroneous data that doesn't apply to the question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fiddled with your menu in firebug and removed the image from it's original location, and placed it as a new element within your menu li:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><img width="303" height="228" src="lib/img/logos/Brandit_Logo.png" alt="Logos" class="MainLogo"></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
         ...
```

Ans then I adjusted the css call for the `li`, adding in:

```
.navbar .nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
```

This should set you on the right track to finish the styling as you need.

In addition, you can remove the `float:left;` from the `.nav` as it isn't needed with the `position:relative;`

Comment: I appreciate the help this got me moving in the right direction.

Comment: Excellent. I see you did a % for the `.nav`... that is definitely better for responsive design.  Glad to help.

Comment: Yes thank you! Im going to have to do a few tweaks to get it proper for mobile but its working well now for desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Make 2 ul elements with 2 li elements both.

```
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>About></li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>Contact</li>
<li>Dropdown</li>
</ul>
```

Place the 1st on the left(before) of your logo and the 2nd on right(after>. Float:left is needed.

Comment: image was absolutely positioned.. this answer wouldn't have helped.