# CSS Center (vertical on line-height and horizontal on page) Div's

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to make a header with the div's centered with a logo in the middle. With the Logo div hanging over, which I've successfully done. I can not however figure out how to place the logo div in the middle of the link divs for the life of me.

Any help would be appreciated, google searching hasn't gotten me any luck, but I'm not sure I know what to search for. I'm not good at making things look pretty normally :(

Page Layout:

- Header (overlay)
- Content (z-index: -1)

Image of site without a float declared on `.headerLogo`
[image]

Image of site with `float: left` declared on `.headerLogo`
[image]

html:

```
<div class='header'>
  <div class='headerLink'>Home</div>
  <div class='headerLink'>Contact</div>
  <div class='headerLogo'></div>
  <div class='headerLink'>Menu</div>
  <div class='headerLink'>Connect</div>
</div>
<div class='content'>
</div>
```

css:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
}
body,html{
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: calibri;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:auto;
}

.header{
  top:0;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: lime 10px solid;
  margin:0;
  position: static;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.headerLink{
  display: inline-block;
  float: center;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.headerLogo{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  position: static;
  background-image: url('/images/logo.jpg');
  background-image: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: lime;
  color: lime;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 100px;

}
.content{
 z-index: -1;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 min-height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: -110px;
 margin-bottom: -50px;
 background-color: #333343;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116296/css-menu-float-half-left-and-half-right/21116467#21116467

Comment: That's with bootstrap, I'm attempting to avoid bootstrap for this. Although that is the outcome I'm looking for. So it may be easier just to grab the bootstrap-min.css

Comment: look at my answer there.. it isn't a `bootstrap` issue...it is a use of proper `css` issue. Post a fiddle here and we can fix it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple ways to go about this. I think the easiest way is to use a fake placeholder to make the horizontal space between menu items in the middle, then have the logo be absolutely positioned on top.

HTML:

```
<div class='header'>
  <div class='headerLink'>Home</div>
  <div class='headerLink'>Contact</div>
  <div class='headerLogo'></div>
  <div class='headerLink headerLogoFake'></div>
  <div class='headerLink'>Menu</div>
  <div class='headerLink'>Connect</div>
</div>
<div class='content'>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.headerLogo{
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  position: static;
  background-image: url('/images/logo.jpg');
  background-image: no-repeat;
  background-position: left top;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-color: lime;
  color: lime;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-100px;
}
.headerLogoFake {
  width:200px;
}
```

As you probably know, if you just leave it as you have, without the float, it'll be in the middle, but it'll push the green bottom border down. This will place a fake empty thing in the middle, but at the same height as the menu items, so won't push it down. It'll add the logo in on top.

Answer (score 0):

Your mark-up provided did not produce the result you were looking for, so I applied the bare minimal styling to accomplish what you are asking for.

Most importantly `float:center;` does not exist.

If you give elements a property of `display:inline-block;`, then you can use `text-align:center;` around the container to center all of the elements.

```
.header {
   text-align:center;
}

.headerLink {
   display:inline-block;
   padding:10px;
}
.headerLogo {
   display:inline-block;
   height:100px; width:100px;
   background:red;
   margin:0px 10px;
}
```

Then, to line them up with your logo, vertically, give them a `vertical-align:top` property and set the margin to near half the width of the logo

http://jsfiddle.net/5V29a/1/ - UPDATED DEMO

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ajhbf/)

```
.headerLogo{
   position:absolute;
   display: inline;
   float: left;
   left 50%
   position: static;
   background-image: url('/images/logo.jpg');
   background-image: no-repeat;
   background-position: left top;
   background-size: 100%;
   margin-left: -50px;
   margin-right: auto;
   background-color: lime;
   color: lime;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   line-height: 100px;
}
```